# Setting values to usercontrol & reloading it

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a usercontrol with two public properties

```
public DateTime fromdate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DateTime toDate
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

I am setting this values in my code behind. After setting the values i want to reload the usercontrol so that it fires a get method which will use these dates ...how will i reload the usercontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx will get you on your way, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged